# Why does Mathematica produce answers involving multiplication by 1?

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting

I have an answer involving multiplication by 1., like

```
-1. Subscript[c, 1]  ...
```

produced by

```
de = -Subscript[b, 1] Subscript[c, 1] E^(-0.291 Subscript[\[Psi], H]) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(1\), \(2\)]\) + 
 Subscript[y, 5] Subscript[\[Psi], 2] Subscript[\[Psi], Hs] + 
 Subscript[\[Psi], Hs] Subscript[\[Psi], V] + 
 Subscript[y, 
  1] (-Subscript[c, 1] E^(-0.291 Subscript[\[Psi], H]) Subscript[y, 5]
      Subscript[\[Psi], 2] + Subscript[b, 1] Subscript[\[Psi], Hs] - 
    Subscript[b, 1] E^(-0.291 Subscript[\[Psi], H])
      k Subscript[\[Psi], Hs] - 
    Subscript[c, 1] E^(-0.291 Subscript[\[Psi], H]) Subscript[\[Psi], 
     V])
Normal[y1 /. Solve[de == 0, y1][[2]]]
```

Comment: It is not exactly 1, there are more digits (not shown).

Comment: I don't think the reason is "invisible" digits at the end of the decimal representation. It is just a choice that was made by WRI long ago to reinterpret `N[Minus[x]]` as ``Times[-1.`,x]``.

Comment: For the calculation it may be easier to replace numeric constants by symbols. Here, for example, you can replace every instance of `-0.291` by a symbol `a`, then solve, and at the end (if desired) substitute `a -> -0.291`. The advantage of this approach is that all numerical quantities involving `a` will be treated exactly the same, and floating-point errors won't cause trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-1. Subscript[c, 1] // Rationalize

(*  -Subscript[c, 1]  *)
```

Have fun!